# QueryFailedError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint Typeorm

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have created the query following the documentation on: https://typeorm.io/update-query-builder

```
await dataSource
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(Order)
    .values(data)
    .execute()
```

But when i run this i get this error:

```
 QueryFailedError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint: "PK_*************"
```

This happened when i upgraded typeorm to the latest version. Previously i was using this syntax:

```
const orderRepo: Repository<Order> = getConnection().getRepository('order');
await orderRepo.insert(data);
```

The new docs say that getConnection is aborted and instead to use data source.
Other operations are still functional like updating a users name and so on.

The primary key for the Order entity looks like this:

```
export class Order extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  order_id!: string;
```

I have just deleted all rows inn the order table, but it still gives me this error:

```
length: 261,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23505',
  detail: 'Key (order_id)=(665bbf44-6e68-4250-9247-60ca2353ff8d) already exists
```

This cannot be true for i have no rows in my database..

Comment: Is your primary key in Order autoincrement?

Comment: Added more inn the question

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will work for everyone but i edited the oder entity and removed the primary key column. Synchronise was set to true and i saved the file and restarted the server.

I then edited the order entity to include the primary key column and that seemed to fix the issue.

Would be cool to get a explanation on why this might have happened i anybody knows :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).